# Call Delphi from C++

Tags: c++, delphi

Trying to pass function pointer from executable created in Delphi to dll function created with Visual C++. When C++ side calls pointer function that has single int type parameter in Delphi side this variable appears as some huge number instead of number '1'. What I do wrong?

C++ side:

```
void (*foo)(int);
extern "C" void _stdcall setFoo(void (*foo2)(int))
{
    foo = foo2;

    foo(1);
}
```

Delphi side:

```
  TFoo = procedure(val: integer) ;
  TSetFoo = procedure( val: TFoo) ; stdcall;
...
  Foo: TFoo;
  SetFoo:TSetFoo;

...

procedure fooH( val : integer);
begin
ShowMessage('foo '+inttostr(val));
end;
...
setFoo(fooH);
```

Comment: Try specifying `stdcall` on the `TFoo` declaration.

Answer (score 3):

You have calling convention mismatches.

`TFoo` on the Delphi side is using Delphi's default `register` convention (`__fastcall` in C++Builder), which Visual C++ does not support at all.

`foo` and `foo2` on the C++ side are using MSVC's default `__cdecl` convention.

So, you need to make `TFoo` and `foo/2` use the same calling convention on both sides, either by:

- making `TFoo` use `cdecl`, and `foo/2` use `__cdecl`:

```cpp
typedef void (__cdecl *fooType)(int);

fooType foo;
extern "C" void __stdcall setFoo(fooType foo2)
{
    foo = foo2;
    foo(1);
}
```

```pascal
type
  TFoo = procedure(val: integer); cdecl;
  TSetFoo = procedure(val: TFoo); stdcall;

var
  Foo: TFoo;
  SetFoo: TSetFoo;

...

procedure fooH( val : integer); cdecl;
begin
  ShowMessage('foo ' + IntToStr(val));
end;

...

setFoo(fooH);
```

- making `TFoo` use `stdcall`, and `foo/2` use `__stdcall`:

```cpp
typedef void (__stdcall *fooType)(int);

fooType foo;
extern "C" void __stdcall setFoo(fooType foo2)
{
    foo = foo2;
    foo(1);
}
```

```pascal
type
  TFoo = procedure(val: integer); stdcall;
  TSetFoo = procedure( val: TFoo); stdcall;

var
  Foo: TFoo;
  SetFoo:TSetFoo;

...

procedure fooH( val : integer); stdcall;
begin
  ShowMessage('foo ' + IntToStr(val));
end;

...

setFoo(fooH);
```

Those are the only 2 calling conventions that are guaranteed to be compatible across different compilers.